# Mean of uniform two-dimensional probability density function

Tags: self-study, mean, expected-value, uniform-distribution, bivariate

I am trying to calculate the mean of a two-dimensional probability density function, which looks like:

[image]

and is defined by

[image]

I know that I can calculate this by

[image]

However, this is where I get stuck, as I cannot see how I am suppose to execute this calculations with vectors.

Comment: The integral you provide is unidimensional...

Comment: More specifically, you want to compute $$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}(x_1,x_2)p(x_1,x_2)\,\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2 = \left(\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}x_1p(x_1,x_2)\,\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2, \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}x_2p(x_1,x_2)\,\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2\right).$$